# How can I fit a symbol that has superscripts and subscripts in table's row?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am using mathematical symbols in a table that has superscripts and sunbcripts ex: `$B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}}$`, which leads it to cross into upper row's section.

I have following code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{1.2pt}
\begin{singlespace}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{{c@{~}X}}
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
        \textbf{Symbol}    & \textbf{Meaning} \\
          \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
          $Z^{\mathrm{pr}}$ & Number of ..     \\
          $R$              & Number of ...    \\
          $B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}}$ & Number of bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla     \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

When you look closely, `pr` of the `B` kind of crosses the other row's section, while `pr` of the `Z` remain on its row. Please note that `$B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}}$` s row is multiline so if possible we can also slightly move it down.

It is possible to keep symbols that have superscripts and subscripts  fit its row in a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change

```
$B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}}$
```

to

```
$B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}\mathstrut}$
```

The `\mathstrut` macro inserts a typographic "strut", i.e., an object with height and depth and no width; hence, it's invisible but leaves a useful trace.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
%% I've simplified the preamble to the bare minimum
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.2pt}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{cX}
  \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
  \textbf{Symbol~}    & \textbf{Meaning}  \\
  \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
  $Z^{\mathrm{pr}}$ & Number of \dots   \\
  $R$               & Number of \dots   \\
  $B_{D}^{\mathrm{pr}\mathstrut}$ % <-- note "\mathstrut"
     & Number of bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
  \addlinespace[0pt]\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Its kind of related but I can ask in a new question. For `$B^{\mathrm{p}}$` `p` is way down , could it be move little up as there was hidden subscript

Comment: When I have `hr` as super script `$\Upsilon_{D}^{\mathrm{hr}\mathstrut}$`, to of `h` kind of touches upper row is it normal ?

Comment: @alper - Just change `$B^{\mathrm{p}}$` to `$Z_{\vphantom{D}}^{\mathrm{p}\mathstrut}$`. And, change `$\Upsilon_{D}^{\mathrm{hr}\mathstrut}$` to `$\Upsilon_{D}^{\mathrm{hr}^{\mathstrut}}$`. Incidentally, `\mathstrut` is defined as `\vphantom{(}`.